# EF multiple key columns one to many

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having trouble with creating a 1 to many relationship on my Products class to ProductSpecification class which has two primary keys ProductId, SpecificationId. The Products Class doesn't always have a ProductSpecification Class does anyone no how to fix my problem Im getting an error to do with upperbound 1. I'm new to EF and doing it code first so if you know what to do please leave a detailed explanation thanks.

Classes:

```
public class ProductSpecification
{      
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public long ProductId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public long SpecificationId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SpecificationId")]
    public virtual Specification Specification { get; set; }
}


public class Specification
{
    [Key]
    public long SpecificationId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product specification name.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product specification value.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SpecificationId")]
    public virtual ICollection<ProductSpecification> ProductSpecs { get; set; }
}
```

DataContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSpecification>().HasKey(x => new { x.ProductId, x.SpecificationId });

modelBuilder.Entity<Specification>().HasOptional(x => x.ProductSpecs)
    .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.SpecificationId);
```

Comment: I think you need to choose between fluent and annotation styles... I mean I don't think you can use *both* to define the same things..

Comment: Do you get the same error if you remove the `modelBuilder` code?

Comment: If I remove the data annotations I get the same error Multiplicity conflicts

Comment: The actual exception text would be helpful.

Comment: try removing the ForeignKey attribute from your Specification class.

Answer (score 0):

Make your ForeignKey nullable:

public long? SpecificationId { get; set; }

public virtual Specification? Specification { get; set; }